# Reinstate green line change bars in Visual Studio after file reopen based on VCS

Tags: visual-studio, svn, version-control

I find the green bars alongside the scroll bar in Visual Studio very helpful, in seeing what changes I have made, especially since the last version control checkin. However, of course, these bars go away when the file is closed and then reopened.  Is there any way to reinstate the green change marks, based on comparing it to some previous version of the file in source control?  I am using SVN/AnkhSVN but if there is such a beast for another VCS that would be great to know about too.

Answer (score 2):

Built-in Track Changes markers in Visual Studio track only the state of saved vs. unsaved changes in a file. See the [description of the Track Changes feature on MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/04/14/track-changes-in-the-editor/).

It seems to me that you are looking for [QuickDiff](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/features/#qdiff) which is unique feature of VisualSVN plug-in. QuickDiff replaces standard Track Changes markers and marks changed lines comparing with [BASE revision](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#idp9284064). In other words, QuickDiff shows you what lines were modified since the last commit.

Comment: A note on your first paragraph - a yellow mark first appears when the file is edited, and then turns green once the file is saved. The green mark does persist until the file is closed.

Comment: @Conrad yes, you a right. My bad, forgot how Track Changes works in VS. To correct this I'll just point to the description of Track Changes on MSDN. TY! ^_^